# Horizontal line in Matlab with date on x axis

Tags: matlab, line, axis

I have a piece of code in Matlab where I need to plot a graph including to lines depending on dates (x axis). I want then to add an horizontal line at y=0 to mimic the x axis as it is not shown due to negative value.

Here is the code:

```
figure1 = figure('Name','Historical Performance');
plot(QuarterEnd,perf(1,:),'b',QuarterEnd,perf(2,:),'r','DatetimeTickFormat','QQQ-y','LineWidth',2)
xlabel('Quarter');
ylabel('Performance');
ax = gca;
ax.XTickLabelRotation=45;
legend('Historical performance from prediction','Best Historical performance','LOcation','Southwest');
```

I have tried something like

```
line(QuarterEnd,[0 0],'Color','g')
```

But it does not span the right interval. I only need the line to be displayed over the interval where there are data points. Is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: Please check, if you can find an answer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33708402/modify-x-axis-position/33711418#33711418) in combination with [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216012/how-to-label-x-axis-with-dates/29216496#29216496).