# How to label x-axis with date in month-day format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, label

I have data of all days through 5 years. I wnat to plot the maxmium value of each day. So, I grouped the data to a DataFrame with 365 rows:

```
dfmax=df.groupby('Day').agg('max')
```

And got the following dataframe:

```
       Data_Value
  Day
  01-01   150
  01-02   180
  01-03   160
```

I want to plot labeling the x-axis with the dates, but the code:

```
plt.plot(dfmax.index,dfmax.Data_Value)
```

Returned an error: *ValueError: could not convert string to float: '12-31'*

I know that I have to convert index to datetime format, and saw some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29216012/how-to-label-x-axis-with-dates), but did not find a way to do it without sepcify an year at the label. I want the labes at month-day format

**EDIT:** 
An example to reproduce the error:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Day':['01-01', '02-01','03-01'], 'Value':[1,6,3]})
plt.figure()
plt.plot(df.Day, df.Value)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `dfmax.plot()`?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: @harvpan I edited with an example to reproduce the error

Comment: `"did not find a way to do it without sepcify an year at the label"` and `"I want the labes at month-day format"` confuses me. If I copy paste your code, it does not give me any error. Moreover, you do not have year in your `Day`. It is highly unclear what do you want as the output.

Comment: @harvpan i think `string` in `plt.plot` is supported by `matplotlib v2.1+`.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47004551/4238408).

Comment: @Oalvinegro, which version are you using?

Comment: @QuangHoang I think that  this solve the problem. I am using an online version, witch is probably older

Comment: My version is 2.0.0